# Github pull request loaded with empty file changes

Tags: github, merge, rebase, cherry-pick

Ok, I've got a problem that I have no idea how to go about solving.

First, a bit of history:

I pulled from my upstream to bring in changes and merged them with the branch I was working in.  At the time, I may have been using a console window with root access.  I say this because I noticed a day later I couldn't save to a lot of the files in my local repo.  I noticed the owner / group had been changed to root and permissions were 644.  After going through and hunting down all of the screwed up files, I then pushed some changes I had made back to my remote working branch.

A week later (now), and I've added several other commits to an open pull request from my remote branch.  In the middle of them was the commit I made after fixing my local repo file permissions.  I noticed it has some 1200 "empty" files (no changes).  I'm a little concerned that merging this pull request upstream could cause big problems and I have no idea how to remove this one commit or if it's even possible...

I tried creating a new branch and using cherry-pick to get all but the one commit, but I've removed files and couldn't merge the older commits that saw a "conflict" between the file that existed at the time and one that no longer exists in the local repo...

Anyway, any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

The solution I used was to reset my local branch to the commit just before the one that I didn't want.  I then copied and pasted the commits after the failed commit into code, recommited, and pushed toa new branch.  Long way around, yes.  But it wasn't bad as I didn't have a lot of code to fix.  A simpler method might have been to use cherry-pick to pull the later commits into my reset local branch, but I tried that at one point and had problems...